# How to get time after 20 minutes from now using carbon in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I want to get the time after 20 minutes from now using carbon in laravel. How can I do that?

```
$minutes = 20;

$delivery_time =Carbon::now()->add($minutes,'minute')->format('h:m');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this:

> Carbon::now()->addMinutes($minutes)->format('h:m')

Documentation: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Comment: Thanks bro. I wrote the time format wrong. it should be like this :
 Carbon::now()->addMinutes($minutes)->format(H:i:s) to get the correct result .

Comment: @Developer No problem, glad to help!